# Изменение весов нейронной сети

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, формулы

Есть формула изменения весов при обратном распространении.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько мне известно,w - вес нейрона,δ - ошибка (желаемый результат отнять полученный),y - выход нейрона, f(e) - функция активации,w' - новый вес.
(Если не прав,то пожалуйста исправьте меня)

Ниже гифка,описывающая изменение весов при обратном распространении.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы узнать,что обозначают символы n,d,e в этой формуле,и как их вычислить.
Буду благодарен за любую помощь.Куда копать совершенно непонятно...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Подкрутка весов]

n(буква греческого алфавита "Эта") скорее всего равна скорости обучения(её не нужно вычислять, вы её сами задаёте)

e - просто переменная функции (как икс, например)

df(e)/de - это производная ф-ии активации

Comment: Как правильно найти функцию активации?

Comment: @deced, насколько я знаю, вы её сами выбираете. К примеру, довольно удобная ф-ия активации - сигмоида (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сигмоида)